Problem with scene loading in unity (code)
I have this bellow script in which i want to make the player go to the "TheUnity" Scene which is a scene for Upgrading PowerUps if the "PickNumber" is above 7, and when it happens i save the previous scene.
My main problem is that if the player moves to the exit of this level it navigates him back to the main menu(the first Scene) instead of the next level of the previous scene.
This is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static LevelManager instance;

    public static LevelManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Level manager is null");
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    { 
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if(instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
            
        
    }




    public static Scene SceneBeforeUnity;

    public void NextLevelCalculation()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "TheUnity")
        {
            int pickNumber;
            pickNumber = Random.Range(0, 10);
            if (pickNumber >= 5)
            {
                SceneBeforeUnity = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
                print("Shop level");
                SceneManager.LoadScene("TheUnity");
                print(SceneBeforeUnity.name);
            }
            else
            {
                print("Next level");
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneBeforeUnity.buildIndex + 1);
            print(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}

I tried to set the scenes correctly on the build Settings

And as it seems from the above code i used "Print" to see which scene is shown as the "SceneBeforeUnity" and the it seems that the correct scene is displayed

"!Shop level"
"!TutorialOfDemo3"

The log you printed is the state before entering the “TheUnity” scene, and it doesn't make any sense. You want to debug the state before exiting, do you?

I see, but it doesn't really matter my main issue is the navigation problem

Is that the only thing in the Console? Is there anything else afterwards? Because if this code is called twice, first time and provided it gets >=5, it will go to the Unity but if it's called again, it will automatically go to the next scene which is MainMenu, since the index wraps around.
